# Вывести изображения товара Woocommerce PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно получить основное и дополнительные изображения, а именно их ссылки. Какие варианты у меня есть?
В карточке товара выводится блок с изображениями этой функцией. Где можно редактировать саму функцию, либо же ее шаблон?

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($product->get_id(), 'shop_catalog');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На странице товара для вывода изображений предусмотрены два действия, которые Вы можете переопределить под себя

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

Для того, чтоб получить главное изображение

```
<?php $post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id(); ?>

<div class="product-welcome__slide"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>" data-fancybox="product-gallery"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>" alt=""></a></div>
```

Дополнительные изображения

```
<?php $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids(); ?>

<?php foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) { ?>
        <div class="product-welcome__slide"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" data-fancybox="product-gallery"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" alt=""></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```